# How to format headers to send with python-requests

Tags: python, http-headers, python-requests

I'm not sure how to get the `headers` in an alphabetical order as the in the example in `python-requests`. Do the brackets and the punctuation such as ' effect the request headers when they are sent?

This is my code:

```
headers = {'oauth_callback': "http://www.website-tm-access.co.nz%2Ftrademe-callback", 
          'oauth_consumer_key' : "5C82CC6BC7C6472154FBC9CAB24A29A2" ,
          'oauth_version': "1.0",
          'oauth_timestamp': time, #int(time.time()),
          'oauth_nonce' : nonce,
          'oauth_signature_method' : "HMAC-SHA1",
          'oauth_signature' : signature
          }


authorization = ', '.join([key + '="' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(str(value)) + '"' for key, value in headers.items()])
http_headers = {'Authorization': authorization}
```

The Output is:

```
  {'Authorization': 'oauth_nonce="62942100", oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fwww.website-tm-access.co.nz%252Ftrademe-callback", oauth_consumer_key="5C82CC6BC7C6472154FBC9CAB24A29A2", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_timestamp="1457345962", oauth_signature="b%27o0rNPtba78EQ3ALsg2mX1Y4vIQw%3D%27", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1"'}
```

The output as defined in the example:

> To make the Authorization header, you simply append all the values
>   starting with “OAuth”. Each value must be URL encoded.

```
  Authorization: OAuth oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fwww.website-tm-access.co.nz%2Ftrademe-callback", oauth_consumer_key="C74CD73FDBE37D29BDD21BAB54BC70E422", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_timestamp="1285532322", oauth_nonce="7O3kEe", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="5s3%2Bel078a5AXGi43FBDyfg5yWY%3D"
```

Comment: Could you show me how can you generated the signature? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The order shouldn't matter when passing the headers to the `requests` module.

You can just do:

```
headers = {'oauth_callback': "http://www.website-tm-access.co.nz%2Ftrademe-callback", 
          'oauth_consumer_key' : "5C82CC6BC7C6472154FBC9CAB24A29A2" ,
          'oauth_version': "1.0",
          'oauth_timestamp': int(time.time()),
          'oauth_nonce' : nonce,
          'oauth_signature_method' : "HMAC-SHA1",
          'oauth_signature' : signature
          }
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: hey i dont think this will work since each value must be URL encoded.